# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, jackson

I am very new to the Jackson parser. My code was running fine until today. I am not able to figure out the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source:  line: 1, column: 1095] (through reference chain: JsonGen["platforms"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:588)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StringDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:90)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.JdkDeserializers$StringDeserializer.deserialize(JdkDeserializers.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:336)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:89)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:290)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:112)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:226)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:203)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:23)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2563)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1789)
at BossMan.candie(BossMan.java:49)
at Hilda.main(Hilda.java:81)
```

Here is the code for URL calling and object mapper:

```
public class BossMan {
public String[] candie () throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
  {
    URL jsonUrl = new URL("http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json");

    ObjectMapper objmapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<JsonGen> jsongen = objmapper.readValue(jsonUrl, new TypeReference<List<JsonGen>>() {});
        String[] shows = new String [jsongen.size()]; 
        int i = 0;
    for(JsonGen element : jsongen) {
      shows[i++]=element.getName();
    }
    return shows;  
  }
}
```

Here is the POJO class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class JsonGen{
  private String _type;
  private List cast;
  private List clips;
  private Common_sense_data common_sense_data;
  private String common_sense_id;
  private List crew;
  private String description;
  private List episodes;
  private Number franchise_id;
  private List genres;
  private String guid;
  private Images images;
  private boolean is_locked;
  private boolean is_mobile;
  private boolean is_parental_locked;
  private String kind;
  private String mobile_networks;
  private String most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
  private String name;
  private List networks;
  private String platforms;
  private List ratings;
  private String release_date;
  private List season_filters;
  private String slug;
  private String tms_id;

  public String get_type(){
    return this._type;
  }
  public void set_type(String _type){
    this._type = _type;
  }
  public List getCast(){
    return this.cast;
  }
  public void setCast(List cast){
    this.cast = cast;
  }
  public List getClips(){
    return this.clips;
  }
  public void setClips(List clips){
    this.clips = clips;
  }
  public Common_sense_data getCommon_sense_data(){
    return this.common_sense_data;
  }
  public void setCommon_sense_data(Common_sense_data common_sense_data){
    this.common_sense_data = common_sense_data;
  }
  public String getCommon_sense_id(){
    return this.common_sense_id;
  }
  public void setCommon_sense_id(String common_sense_id){
    this.common_sense_id = common_sense_id;
  }
  public List getCrew(){
    return this.crew;
  }
  public void setCrew(List crew){
    this.crew = crew;
  }
  public String getDescription(){
    return this.description;
  }
  public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
  }
  public List getEpisodes(){
    return this.episodes;
  }
  public void setEpisodes(List episodes){
    this.episodes = episodes;
  }
  public Number getFranchise_id(){
    return this.franchise_id;
  }
  public void setFranchise_id(Number franchise_id){
    this.franchise_id = franchise_id;
  }
  public List getGenres(){
    return this.genres;
  }
  public void setGenres(List genres){
    this.genres = genres;
  }
  public String getGuid(){
    return this.guid;
  }
  public void setGuid(String guid){
    this.guid = guid;
  }
  public Images getImages(){
    return this.images;
  }
  public void setImages(Images images){
    this.images = images;
  }
  public boolean getIs_locked(){
    return this.is_locked;
  }
  public void setIs_locked(boolean is_locked){
    this.is_locked = is_locked;
  }
  public boolean getIs_mobile(){
    return this.is_mobile;
  }
  public void setIs_mobile(boolean is_mobile){
    this.is_mobile = is_mobile;
  }
  public boolean getIs_parental_locked(){
    return this.is_parental_locked;
  }
  public void setIs_parental_locked(boolean is_parental_locked){
    this.is_parental_locked = is_parental_locked;
  }
  public String getKind(){
    return this.kind;
  }
  public void setKind(String kind){
    this.kind = kind;
  }
  public String getMobile_networks(){
    return this.mobile_networks;
  }
  public void setMobile_networks(String mobile_networks){
    this.mobile_networks = mobile_networks;
  }
  public String getMost_recent_full_episode_added_date(){
    return this.most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
  }
  public void setMost_recent_full_episode_added_date(String most_recent_full_episode_added_date){
    this.most_recent_full_episode_added_date = most_recent_full_episode_added_date;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }
  public List getNetworks(){
    return this.networks;
  }
  public void setNetworks(List networks){
    this.networks = networks;
  }
  public String getPlatforms(){
    return this.platforms;
  }
  public void setPlatforms(String platforms){
    this.platforms = platforms;
  }
  public List getRatings(){
    return this.ratings;
  }
  public void setRatings(List ratings){
    this.ratings = ratings;
  }
  public String getRelease_date(){
    return this.release_date;
  }
  public void setRelease_date(String release_date){
    this.release_date = release_date;
  }
  public List getSeason_filters(){
    return this.season_filters;
  }
  public void setSeason_filters(List season_filters){
    this.season_filters = season_filters;
  }
  public String getSlug(){
    return this.slug;
  }
  public void setSlug(String slug){
    this.slug = slug;
  }
  public String getTms_id(){
    return this.tms_id;
  }
  public void setTms_id(String tms_id){
    this.tms_id = tms_id;
  }
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
public class Hilda {
public static boolean b ;
public static WebDriver driver;
public static int countingCrows(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{
  int i,j=0,k=0;
  for(i=1; i<=2; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=6; j++){
      if(!(i==1&&j==6)){
        b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div["+i+"]/ul/li["+j+"]/div/a/img")).isEnabled();
        k++;
        //System.out.println("k inner loop:"+k);
      }
      if(i==1&&j==5){
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        try{
          boolean c = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[6]/div/a/img")).isEnabled();
          if(c){
            k++;
            //System.err.println("k inside j==5 for sixsth element:"+k);
          }
        }catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("sixsth elemnet not found in first row");
        }
      }
    }
    if(i==1&&j==5){
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='carousel-control left']")).click();
    }
  }
  System.out.println("total no :"+k);
  return k;
}

public static String[] unchained(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException{
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  int j = countingCrows(driver);
  int i,k=0;
  String[] singleText1 = new String[11];
  if(j==11){
  for(i=1; i<=2; i++){
    for(j=1; j<=6; j++){
      if(!(i==1&&j==6)){
        singleText1[k] = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div["+i+"]/ul/li["+j+"]/div/a/img")).getAttribute("id");
        //boolean b = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div["+i+"]/ul/li["+j+"]/div/a/img")).isEnabled();
        //System.out.print(j-1+"-"+singleText1[k]); System.out.println("-"+b);
        k++;
      }else {
        System.err.println("element div[1] div[6] is not present");
      }
    }
    if(j==5){
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='carousel-control left']")).click();
      }
    }
  }
  return singleText1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
  WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.dishanywhere.com");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  String [] cottonSack =unchained(driver);
  System.out.println("*******************************************************");
  int j = countingCrows(driver);
  /*for(int i= 0;i<=j-1;i++){
    System.out.println(cottonSack[i]);
  }*/

  BossMan calvin = new BossMan();
    String[] dogs = calvin.candie();
    for(int k=0;k<cottonSack.length;k++){
      boolean c = dogs[k].equalsIgnoreCase(cottonSack[k]);
      if(c){
        System.out.println("Comparing json data- " +dogs[k]+" with webpage data- "+cottonSack[k]+" and Result is- "+c);
      }else {
        System.out.println("Comparing json data- " +dogs[k]+" with webpage data- "+cottonSack[k]+" Result- "+c);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you have start array token `[` in your JSON but your java class expects a string. Map it to a `String[]` or `List<String>` maybe

Comment: @gerrytan Thanks , please if you can elaborate and specify the location where these changes would go.

Comment: Sorry only you know the answer to that. That's a very long code and it's not a nice thing to ask member of community here to do your work for you

Comment: @Shek ... in the JSON.  At or near column 1095 of line 1.  Or, if you are talking about code changes, it depends on the JSON you are attempting to read.

Comment: private String bracket;
    public String getBracket() {
  return bracket;
 }
 public void setBracket(String bracket) {
  this.bracket = bracket;
 }

Comment: @StephenC The main function calls selenium to gather the name of the shows and jackson parser to gather the data from API and later compare, but while running it throws error about "Can not deserialize instance" at Source: http://www.dishanywhere.com/radish/v20/dol/home/carousels/shows.json;

Answer (score 35):

The error is:

> Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY
>   token at [Source:  line: 1, column: 1095] (through reference chain:
>   JsonGen["**platforms**"])

In JSON, `platforms` look like this:

```
"platforms": [
    {
        "platform": "iphone"
    },
    {
        "platform": "ipad"
    },
    {
        "platform": "android_phone"
    },
    {
        "platform": "android_tablet"
    }
]
```

So try change your pojo to something like this:

```
private List platforms;

public List getPlatforms(){
    return this.platforms;
}

public void setPlatforms(List platforms){
    this.platforms = platforms;
}
```

**EDIT**: you will need change `mobile_networks` too.  Will look like this:

```
private List mobile_networks;

public List getMobile_networks() {
    return mobile_networks;
}

public void setMobile_networks(List mobile_networks) {
    this.mobile_networks = mobile_networks;
}
```

Comment: Which import statement do you use for List?

Comment: @StephenKuehl same as used in the question, `java.util.List`

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes instead of just string you might receive list of strings. That's why you will get this error. In those cases, just use data type as Object. this solves the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).