# Jackson: How to unmarshal a property with JSON content as raw String

Tags: json, jackson, marshalling

I am marshalling an object into JSON that has JSON in a String property (String actionsJSON). This was causing that JSON to be escaped, so I am using Jackson annotation @JsonRawValue to get the JSON in that property not be escaped. The problem is that when I unmarshal it back into a String property (the reverse process) Jackson processes the JSON (which has a JSON array) and throws an error as the java class property is just a String:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
```

How can I make Jackson just copy the content of that property without trying to process it so I have JSON code inside the String property as I had in the original object?

(I have tried @JsonRawValue in the target class, ... @JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class, as = StringSerializer.class) but error is still there.

Comment: Do you generate the content of `actionsJSON`? Any chance you could keep it as an `Object` and let Jackson serialize it?

Comment: I generate it manually into the String as is dynamic content not related to Java properties, that is why I need @JsonRawValue so Jackson does not re-convert it into JSON twice (escaping it) when marshalling. The problem is not really serialising but when I deserialise it back into the String property.

Comment: @icordoba the problem is that @JsonRawValue is only for serialization, not deserialization. Using an `Object` instead of a String and letting Jackson serialize (and deserialize) would fix the issue.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783421/how-can-i-include-raw-json-in-an-object-using-jackson and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137060/jackson-deserialize-variable-as-json-string

Comment: My problem is probably the same one as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911591/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-lang-string-out-of-start-array-token

Comment: I have also tried changing from String to Object in the target class as @GuiSim suggested. Even though I wanted to avoid removing the String type, at least I don't get an error now as I get a generic ArrayList into it without any error. Anyway, my goal is just getting the JSON as text into the String.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783421/how-can-i-include-raw-json-in-an-object-using-jackson

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Json**De**serlalize and not JsonSerialize. 
A nice example at [Deserialize JSON to string in raw format using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117558/deserialize-json-to-string-in-raw-format-using-jackson)
And more detailed information at http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations