# Deserialize JSON to string in raw format using Jackson

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a use case where I want the JSON to be converted to string as it is, but it is failing and giving me null, here is my POJO:

```
@Data
@JsonSnakeCase
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DocumentTemplateRequest {

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TemplateState state;


@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonAsStringDeserializer.class)
private String inputSchema;

}
```

the Json I am using as payload:

```
{
"state": "staging",
"input_schema": {
    "title": "Person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["firstName", "lastName"]
}

}
```

I am using object mapper for mappings:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DocumentTemplateRequest documentTemplateRequest = null;
    try {
        documentTemplateRequest = objectMapper.readValue(str, DocumentTemplateRequest.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is my deserializer:

```
public class JsonAsStringDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {
@Override
public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    TreeNode tree = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    return tree.toString();

}
}
```

and the results of deserialization is :

```
state : staging
inputSchema: null
```

why inputSchema is coming as null, what am I missing?

Comment: @someguy76, the question is about Java

Comment: you should check the value of `tree` with debugger. also, how do you know that `toString{}` produces desired result? perhaps you should pass the tree to an `ObjectMapper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is with the property?
you are missing underscroe. input_schema is different from inputSchema.

either use the same property name everywhere you use it or use jsonproperty annotation to be sepecific.

Comment: I have already used @JsonSnakeCase annotation which does this task for me.

Comment: Somehow putting @JsonProperty("input_schema") worked for me. not sure why @JsonSnakeCase didn't work here, thanks anyway :)